# submiting empty value after submit

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have 3 forms here `query.php` is for handling the query of the table,
`salesorder_table.php` is for outputting the table and the `data_fetch_table` is for initializing the `salesorder_table`.

my problem is when i try to var_dump `$SALESORDER_CODE` it gave me empty string and icant execute my query because of that what should i do ?

**query.php**

```
$SALESORDER_CODE=$_POST["SALESORDER_CODE"];
var_dump($SALESORDER_CODE);
$salesorder=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT* FROM salesorder WHERE
 USER_ID='".$display_userid."' AND SALESORDER_CODE = '".$SALESORDER_CODE."'");
```

**salesorder_table.php**

```
<?php


       include ("query.php");
    echo '
        <table id="example1"  class="datatable table table-bordered table-striped" >
                            <thead>


            <tr class="default">
                                <th class="display_invisible">ID</th>
                                <th></t h>
                                <th>Item Code <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i> </th>
                                <th>Quantity <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                                <th>Rate <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                                <th>Total <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    <tbody>';

    while($sorow=mysqli_fetch_array($salesorder)){

        $SALESORDER_ID=$sorow["SALESORDER_ID"];
        $SALESORDER_QUANTITY=$sorow["SALESORDER_QUANTITY"];
        $SALESORDER_UNITPRICE=$sorow["SALESORDER_UNITPRICE"];   
        $SALESORDER_AMOUNT=$sorow["SALESORDER_AMOUNT"];
        $ITEM_ID=$sorow["ITEM_ID"];
        $total= number_format($SALESORDER_AMOUNT, 2);

    $itemquery=mysqli_query($link,"select * from item where ITEM_ID = '".$ITEM_ID."'");
    while($itemrow=mysqli_fetch_array($itemquery)){

        $ITEM_NAME=$itemrow["ITEM_NAME"];
    }


    ?>          
     <tr class="datatablefetch">
    <td class="display_invisible"><?php  echo $SALESORDER_ID ?></td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li class="bg-success"><a  href="" title="Edit Customer Info"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editso">Edit</a></li>
             <li class="bg-danger"><a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteitemmodal" href="" title="Inactive Customer ">Delete</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </td>

     <td class="text-center"><?php echo $ITEM_NAME; ?></td>
     <td class="text-center"><?php echo $SALESORDER_QUANTITY; ?></td>
     <td class="text-center"><?php echo $SALESORDER_UNITPRICE; ?></td>
     <td class="text-center 
     <?php 
     if($ITEM_ID != "3"){
         echo 'amount';
     }else{
     echo 'discount'; 
     }?>"><?php echo $total;?></td>


     </tr>
    <?php
    }
     echo'
      </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr class="default">
                                <th class="display_invisible">ID</th>
                                                            <th></th>
                                <th>Item Code <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i> </th>
                                <th>Quanitity <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                                <th>Rate <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                                <th>Total <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>';


    ?>
```

**fetch_data_table.js**

```
function fetch_data(){
             setTimeout(function(){
      SALESORDER_CODE = "SALESORDER_CODE";
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",  
      data: SALESORDER_CODE,      
      url: "php/salesorder_table.php",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
         $("#tabledata").html(data);
        } 
        });
        });
            }   
    $(document).ready(function() {
    fetch_data();   
    })
```

Comment: look at your console and use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php. I don't see anything related to `SALESORDER_CODE`, other than in your JS.

Comment: i already used it

Comment: fred can you help me in this problem :((

Comment: your data should be like that `data: {SALESORDER_CODE: "SALESORDER_CODE" }` as key-value pair